# What is a Q-LOC axle? Is it compatible with Quick Release?

Tags: wheels, parts, fork, axle

So what is a Q-LOC axle? If I decide to install a fork with such an axle, do I need another front wheel or is is it possible that my current QR hub is compatible. What do a Q-LOC wheel look like and how much do they cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appers that Q-LOC is the name SR SunTour gives to  through-hole axes, such as [this one](http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/dstore/products/Q-LOC/3632/Q-LOC/15QLCTi.html). In **[this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16448/why-are-people-with-full-suspension-bikes-concerned-about-stiffness-added-by-t)**, the advantages are explained. They are not compatible with traditional QR, because of the difference in the diameter.